# How to reference an element in an array when including a layout and passing variable, for android data binding?

Tags: android, xml, layout, data-binding

I am using the android data binding library and it has proven very effective, but I have run into a small problem. I have a container view , which includes two views of similar layout , and then change their content based on the data.

the variable for my container is

```
 <variable
        name="highlights"
        type="no.norsktipping.services.android.mappers.sports.SportsFeedMapper.Highlights" />
```

And it works perfectly fine to use it likes this :

```
android:visibility="@{highlights.highLightMatches.size() == 0 ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"
```

but when it comes to sending highLightMatch objects to my included views , it does not seem to support it. Namely , this does not compile :

```
        <include layout="@layout/highlight_cell"
        bind:highlight="@{highlights.highLightMatches[0]}"
        bind:handlers="@{handlers}"

        android:id="@+id/cell1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

The variable in highlight_cell is

```
   <variable
        name="highlight"
        type="no.norsktipping.services.android.domain.sports.HighlightsMatch" />
```

and highlights.highLightMatches is a list of that type.

I realize there is probably supported methods for solving this with recyclerViews or similar , but in this case, I will not have a huge amount of views, so recycling should not be necessary.

My question, is if this is possible and what the correct syntax is?

Some work arounds :

- sending highlights to highlight_cell together with an index
- in the container , having variables Highlight1 , Highlight2 etc

Here is the code where I inflate my container layout :

```
        HighlightsMatch match = HighlightsMatch.builder()
            .setInfo("Info")
            .setIsLive(true)
            .setScoreInfo("1 - 0")
            .setTotalAmountOfBetObjects(3)
            .setTitle("title")
            .build();

    HighlightsMatch match2 = HighlightsMatch.builder()
            .setInfo("Info")
            .setIsLive(false)
            .setScoreInfo("1 - 0")
            .setTotalAmountOfBetObjects(3)
            .setTitle("title")
            .setActionUrl("lol")
            .setHubObject(betObject)
            .build();

    SportsFeedMapper.Highlights highlights =new SportsFeedMapper.Highlights();
    highlights.highLightMatches.add(match);
    highlights.highLightMatches.add(match2);

    HighlightscontainerBinding binding = HighlightscontainerBinding.inflate(inflater,(ViewGroup)root.findViewById(R.id.container),true);
    binding.setHandlers(new HighlightCellHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClickToGamble(String gambleUrl) {
            Log.d("BOB","click;");
        }
    });
    binding.setHighlights(highlights);
```

and the compiler error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':NTAPPNext:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Found data binding errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Identifiers must have user defined types from the XML file. highlight is missing it
>   file:C:\Users\havch\Documents\work\android\norsk-tipping-android\NTAPPNext\src\main\res\layout\highlightscontainer.xml
>   loc:69:56 - 69:64
>   ****\ data binding error ****

Comment: What is on highlightscontainer.xml on line 69? The error is pointing to it saying that you are using a variable 'highlight' that hasn't been declared. Perhaps it is a typo and you meant 'highlights'?

Comment: It's a bit embarrassing to reply to this , but that's life. You are right, it must have been a typo. I tested now, and it works as expected.